# Are there any limits to the Hit Dice an artificer can apply to Homonculi

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron, artificer

I am playing an artificer who is built around improving his homunculi rather than combat and as such I stared looking into ways to improve them, the most obvious being their Hit Dice.

i was wondering if there is a limit to how many hit die I can have on a single Homunculus(Which is an Iron Defender.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

> ## *Eberron Campaign Setting* pg. 32
>
> ### Artificer
>
> #### Craft Homunculus (Ex)
>
> An artificer’s homunculus can have as many Hit Dice as his master’s Hit Dice minus 2.